# Sultan's Zoo Secret Passage

Tags: prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time

I'm playing Prince of Persia: The Sands of Time right now and I'm at the level called "The Sultan's Zoo". If anyone remembers, in the area where you fight those first birds, there's rectangular hole in the ground.

The hole/ slot is right in front of the gate you came through (or over, actually) and has two torches pinned to the wall above it. If you go near it, the prince says "I wonder what this this for..." — I haven't been able to figure it out, does anyone know what that slot is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, nevermind. I progressed a bit and it turns out there was nothing interesting about it. Later in that level you pull a switch that causes a ladder to come out of the slot, to help your less agile companion reach the same place as you.